# SoapUI 5.0 Create cookie

Tags: rest, soapui

I'm trying to run a REST project and have inserted securitytoken and session into my header.
But I get an errormessage telling me that a cookie is missing (since my service needs a cookie to run successful).

I have tried to do this with Groovy:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport
def myCookieStore = HttpClientSupport.getHttpClient().getCookieStore()

import org.apache.http.impl.cookie.BasicClientCookie
def myNewCookie = new BasicClientCookie("mycookiename", "mycookievalue")
myNewCookie.version = 1
myNewCookie.domain = "my domain as IP"
myCookieStore.addCookie(myNewCookie)
```

But its still throwing me the same errormessage.
Are there any solution to inject a cookie as a header in SoapUI 5.0?

Comment: This is the correct approach. Check with your dev if you have the right values.

Comment: tosh, not sure if you still live with the problem. Just in case, you may take a look at [this](https://github.com/nmrao/soapUIGroovyScripts/blob/master/groovy/AddCookiesToNextRequest.groovy) example

Comment: @Rao Your approach will **not** work for creating cookies. See https://siking.wordpress.com/2013/07/25/soapui-cookie-management/ if interested.

Comment: While I agree if that is the case if some one needs to create the cookie. However in the case of my example, I understand that user is not creating cookie for him self, instead he would get it from previous response header called `Set-Cookie` and send it in the current header.

Answer (score 1):

I would have like to add this as a comment, but I don't have 50 reputation yet.

Don't know if you are still working on this, but anyway:

Like Rao says it seems like you want to work in a session with a negotiated token. You can go three ways with this in soapui.

1. Like you propose: create the cookie and the values from scratch. That would be a good use case when you want to test which values are going to pass and which values or combos thereof will return errors or different kinds of messages.
2. If you want to test anything else then the headers, then you can load a certificate, go to the authentication link and retrieve your tokens and session IDs from the headers in the Set-Cookies as proposed by Rao.
3. Option number three, my personal favourite when testing other things than headers, is to trust SoapUI to take care of it. You can do this by setting the test case to remember your session. You can set this setting in the testcase settings menu. It is called something the likes of 'Maintain http session'.

Remark: In soapui you can modularize tests. You could for example make a testcase for the authentication in an 'util' test suite. This because you can then disable the util test suite to prevent it from running as a dead-weight test. You can then call to this testcase anywhere to invoke the authentication procedure. For this to work you have to set the settings for the 'Run Testcase' (it is named somehting like that) to 'transport the http session to and from this test case' and, like before, set the parent testcase to 'Maintain HTTP Session'. More info on modularization: https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/modularizing-your-tests.html.

For the security certificate import, check this smartbear example: https://www.soapui.org/resources/blog/ws-security-settings.html